# How do I get Spring security to generate the same password as what the Jasypt command line tool generates?

Tags: spring, spring-security, jasypt

I'm using Jasypt 1.9.0, Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE, and Maven 3.0.3.  Using the Jasypt command line tool, I generate passwords like so …

```
./digest.sh input=admin providerClassName=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider algorithm=SHA-256  saltGeneratorClassName=org.jasypt.salt.ZeroSaltGenerator
```

However, when I configure Spring security to attempt to match a password someone entered at the login screen …

```
<beans:bean id="bcProvider" class="org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider" />

<beans:bean id="jasyptStringDigester" class="org.jasypt.digest.StandardStringDigester">
    <beans:property name="algorithm">
        <beans:value>SHA-256</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="provider">
        <beans:ref bean="bcProvider" />
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="saltGenerator">
        <beans:bean id="saltGenerator" class="org.jasypt.salt.ZeroSaltGenerator"/>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- This Spring Security-friendly PasswordEncoder implementation will -->
<!-- wrap the StringDigester instance so that it can be used from -->
<!-- the security framework. -->
<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.jasypt.spring.security3.PasswordEncoder">
    <property name="stringDigester">
        <ref bean="jasyptStringDigester" />
    </property>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" id="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="sbdUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Spring is generating a different password than what is stored, and hence I'm not able to authenticate my user.  Is there some configuration I'm missing?  Why, during authentication, does SPring generate something different than what Jasypt has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you run `digest.sh` multiple times you will get different hashes for same input values. i assume Jasypt uses a timestamp or a random string as a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29).

to be able to generate same hash, you must know the salt, which is used or control the way it is generated. There is a cli parameter called `saltGeneratorClassName`. By providing a class, which implements the [SaltGenerator](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.8/org/jasypt/salt/SaltGenerator.html) interface you can control the salt generation.

**UPDATE:**

forget what i said about position of the salt. you just need to change the `jasyptStringDigester` a little bit:

```
<beans:bean id="jasyptStringDigester" class="org.jasypt.digest.StandardStringDigester">
    <beans:property name="algorithm">
        <beans:value>SHA-256</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="provider">
        <beans:ref bean="bcProvider" />
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="saltGenerator">
        <beans:ref bean="saltGenerator" />
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="impl.of.your.SaltGenerator" id="saltGenerator" />
```

and then you need to provide `impl.of.your.SaltGenerator` to `digest.sh`:

```
./digest.sh input=admin \
    providerClassName=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider \
    algorithm=SHA-256 \
    saltGeneratorClassName=impl.of.your.SaltGenerator
```

Comment: Hi, I added Jasypt's ZeroSaltGenerator (see my edits) as per your direction, but am still not authenticating in my Spring app.

Comment: @Dave then the hash is not your problem. i have used the following code snippet to verify that `digest.sh` and `StandardStringDigester` create the same hash: http://pastie.org/5516953

Comment: You're right -- my PASSWORD column in my database was too short.  Adding more characters fixed the problem and you're suggestion worked.

Comment: glad you was able to fix your problem.